# IIS with multiple roots

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

Can IIS7 be setup to have many roots? 
Say I have a local server on our LAN called jupiter. Staff can view their sites via a folder structure such as http://jupiter.example.com/staff/karen. 
While this works ok, what they cannot do is use relative addressing to its full. 
Should they wish to link to a home page then using href="/default.html" or something similar will take then to the root of jupiter and not to their own top directory.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I know I can use ports (i.e. http://jupiter.example.com:1001) to get to karens site, but I would much prefer something like http://karen.jupiter.example.com -or- http://jupiter.example.com/~karen) where accessing the root will take them to the top of their own site structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server presents a single namespace to all connections. This is different to the `NET USE /HOME` command that maps the users home directory to the root of the mount point.

Your idea to use either alternative convention with with a renaming mapper is possible. There is a supported URL rewriter available at [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). This is supplied with samples for typical scenarios.

Alternately you could simply change your host absolute paths `/default.html` to `default.html`. This would allow the pages to contain only relative paths and even permit them to be moved within the folder hierarchy.

Comment: thanks, but I dont wholey understand I am afraid.  Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or something?  I appreciate I can do the relative addressing.  However, when you have folders multiple levels deep, then to get back home, my colleagues would find it easier to use /default.html as opposed to ../../../../default.html (or similar) and having to work that out for each nav bar on each page.

Comment: You could provide a remapping service to the users that provides a helper to the users. something like http://server/Default?user=... to redirect the user to the expected location.